# MinWidth property of MainWindow is bound but doesn't work - how can I get it done in MVVM and using settings class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am preparing simple app and when I click button to show some additional info, I would like the width of Main Window to grow. And it works but at the same time I would like to set it's MinWidth property to some value, to prevent users from hiding this additional content.

I have class to store Width and MinWidth properties. I am binding Width to this class with Mode=TwoWay and do the same with MinWidth. But it doesn't work.

```cs
public class MainWindowSettings
{
    public uint Width { get; set; }
    public uint MinWidth { get; set; }
}
```

```
<Window
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
MinHeight="330" 
MinWidth="{Binding ButtonsVM.MainWindowSettings.MinWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" 
Width="{Binding ButtonsVM.MainWindowSettings.Width, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

```
class ButtonsViewModel
{
        public MainWindowSettings MainWindowSettings
        {
            get { return _mainWindowSettings; }

            private set
            {
                _mainWindowSettings = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        } 


        private void ButtonClick(string signOrNumber)
        {
            if (signOrNumber == "showAdvanced")
            {
                MainWindowSettings.Width += 80;
                MainWindowSettings.MinWidth = 290;
            }
        }  
}
```

Comment: `MainWindowSettings` needs to [implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification).

Comment: At least it's more future proof for screens with sizes up to `uint.MaxValue` than the default `int.MaxValue`. :)

Comment: Is `Window.MinWidth` actually a `DependencyProperty`?

Comment: @Silvermind Yes, it's a dependency property. And the XAML editor would be hassling him if it weren't, so he'd know. If we can assume that `ButtonsVM` is a property of the window's DataContext, and it's of type `ButtonsViewModel`, the problem is that he's not raising any change notifications in the property setters of `MainWindowSettings`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It works, thank you. My question is why Width doesn't need this interface?

Comment: `MainWindowSettings` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and all the properties of `MainWindowSettings` need to raise `PropertyChanged` appropriately in their setters. If you're not raising that event in Width, I think you got lucky in this particular case and the value you're setting for `MinWidth` is causing the window to update the way you want it to anyway, but there is no magic here. All bound viewmodel properties need to raise that event.

Comment: Ok, I will remember now. Thank you so much.